# Check if dynamically created textbox is dirty with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on MVC 3 application, I have managed to create a dynamically created textboxes using partial view with validations for these dynamic boxes, however, I want to check if these dynamic textboxes are changed and change a hidden field value to 'dirty' accordingly, I use the following code to detect any changes on textboxes and it works OK on any already existed textboxes, but it doesn't work on dynamically created textboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type='text']").change(function () {
            $("#FormState").val('dirty');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there anyway to do this with javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   $("input[type='text']").live('change',function () {
        $("#FormState").val('dirty');
    });
```

[JQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is called **event delegation**. jQuery currently offers three ways to do event delegation, with `live`, `delegate`, and `on`.

The other answer suggested using `live`, but it and `delegate` are deprecated for good reason. They have some performance problems. You should use `on` for event delegation. In order to use it best you need to give it a reasonable parent element of these inputs. Try to choose the closest parent to all of your inputs.

```
$('#parent-id').on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
    $("#FormState").val('dirty');
});
```